# Is it safe to use curly brackets to mimic regions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, scope

I started using something like this

```
        ...declarations

        //Retrieve & display
        {
            self.Items = ko.observableArray();
            self.TotalCount = ko.observable();
            self.Columns = ko.observableArray(parameters.columns.filter(function (item) { return ko.observable(item) }));
            self.NoResults = ko.observable(false); //Used when filters return no results
            self.NoMoreResults = ko.observable(false); //Used when infinite scroll reached end
            self.Loading = ko.observable(false); //True between ajax call start and completion
        }

        ...more declarations
```

to try to organize & group my variable declarations, which I can expand and collapse at will.

Do stray curly brackets like these affect things like scope? My code seems to run fine, but I want to know for sure, as the VS intellisense is sometimes not happy, and I can't find a clarifying answer.

Comment: _Do stray curly brackets like these affect things like scope?_ No, it doesn't except for `let` and `const`.

Answer (score 1):

> the **VS** intellisense is sometimes not happy

It *should* be safe, as Javascript is function scoped (except for `let`). But since you are already using Visual Studio, why not use the [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) extension instead, which comes with a collapsible [region](http://vswebessentials.com/features/javascript#regions) directive?

[image: regions]

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

In short only functions create new scope in javascript.

It is better to extract such code in a function. That way you also give the block a descriptive name in addition to combining the expressions.